# Hooker calls K an "A-Boy" -- what does that term mean?

Tags: blade-runner-2049

My best guess, assuming I heard rightly, is "android" but so is she an android although the term is not used at all -- of course the term used throughout is "replicant." The other idea is that this is it is sort of a compliment, as in "A Team" but I sure don't find that compelling. It could be an insult but I don't think she means to obviously insult him and in fact she likes him, it seems like and is frustrated by his profound indifference.

Grasping at straws: "Alone" boy?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure she means android-boy

Comment: although the book of course even in the title uses the term android (does it use "replicant" at all?) is the word "android" used in either movie? if you were a replicant hooker would you call another replicant an "android" or a shortened form of it? i am very interested in how replicants thinks; I liked the catty hostility/jealousy twixt the hooker and Joi -- they really disliked each other even though, or maybe because, their minds were of perhaps identical design (if that is true -- i would try to leverage my AI division into as many products as possible.

Comment: You heard right [Doxie#2 Page 30 of shooting script](https://thescriptsavant.com/pdf/blade_runner%20(2049).pdf).

Comment: My immediate guess would be "artificial", as in the real term "a-life".